# I want to put a document into a folder (shared, private on first use) from Xpages

Tags: xpages

I have a button. With the button I want to put the current document into a folder that is private. I use putinfolder for Java. It works great for me, but not for the others. The documents only in my private folder not in theirs.
What can I do to put into the right folder? How can I do this with JS in the frontend?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the code runs under signer identity. My advice is to transfer the code to an agent with parameter "Run as web user".

Comment: Bear in mind frontend JS cannot move a document in the backend, unless you're calling server-side code (e.g. via an AJAX request, which is what the XPages partial refreshes do). All client-side JS can influence is the browser, the HTML on the page.

Comment: Are you saying that it goes into your folder when you do it, not into theirs? Or are you saying that when they do it, it doesn't go into their folder?

Comment: If I put in folder, the document is in MY folder. If an other person put in folder, then the document is also in MY folder. Strange. I have tried to sign the an other signer, but it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* actually do this using clientside JS if you use the RPC control. Your code to perform the operation will have to be in backend code like Paul pointed out. But the you can call the code using clientside javascript which is what I think you are asking.

1. First write a public method in java on a managed bean that performs the move to folder.  It sounds like you know how to do that. You want your bean to be bound to sessionScope.
2. Next create an RPC control which is called "Remote Service" in design mode.  Give it a `serviceName` which is how you will reference it.

[image]

3. Create a method that will call your java method. Also create an argument if you want to choose which folder to put it into. Your code will look similar to below.

   ```
   <xe:jsonRpcService id="jsonRpcService2" serviceName="yourRPC">
      <xe:this.methods>
       <xe:remoteMethod
           script="yourBean.putInFolder(folderName);">
           <xe:this.arguments>
               <xe:remoteMethodArg name="folderName"
                   type="string">
               </xe:remoteMethodArg>
           </xe:this.arguments>
       </xe:remoteMethod>
   </xe:this.methods></xe:jsonRpcService>
   ```
4. Call the code from clientside javascript. It will look roughly like this:

   ```
   var folder = "Stuff"
   yourRPC.putInFolder(folder);
   ```

Note: As pointed out in the comments. In your java method, you will want to write it so that it runs under the users authority, not yours. When you obtain the current Session, don't use "sessionAsSigner".

I wrote some about RPC is this blog post: http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2014/10/my-first-experience-using-json-rpc.html

To *really* understand how the RPC works read this from Tim Tripcony: http://www.notesin9.com/2014/05/21/tim-explains-json-rpc-codefortim/

Comment: Wow, thx for that. I will try it.
My java function is already in a bean. Now I must do it.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it answered your question

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to try this? I think this will answer your question of how to call the backend java from the front end JS, I am less confident that the backend method will actually put documents in each users folder.  If this did work, then please accept the answer, thx :)